# PHP If Else shows always ELSE and prints the variable

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a plugin that let's me get custom fields. The theme I'm working is for a magazine, and some writers have twitter accounts and some don't.

I want to show a different box in each of those cases.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    $twit = the_field('twitter'); 
    ?>

    <?php 
        if (!empty($twit)) { 
    ?>

                     <p> <?php the_field( 'autor' ); ?>  |  <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo rawurlencode ( the_field( 'twitter' )); ?>" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="es" data-dnt="true">Seguir a @<?php echo rawurlencode ( the_field( 'twitter' )); ?></a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>  |  <?php the_field( 'fotos' ); ?>  |</p>

    <?php } else { ?>

           <p>Nothing to see here</p>

    <?php } ?>
```

The "nothing to see here" paragraph is just to test, the idea is to get the info from autor and fotos and create a different sentence.

My problem with this code is that in any case, I get the Nothing to see here message, and if the twit field exists, it gets printed, and from trial and error, it looks that it gets printed from when I create the variable `$twit`.

Comment: use var_dump to check variable, this will help to debug.

Comment: Did you try `if($twit != "")`?

Comment: @ПавелИванов When the twitter field exists, it gets printed on the side but if I use the var_dump, it shows the NULL next to it. For example, if twitter is Foobar, it shows FoobarNULL. When twitter doesn't exist, it only shows NULL.

Comment: @Howlin Tried it, same results as before. I think the variable is not getting "injected" (don't know if that's the right term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong function.

[the_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/) will echo out the content of that field, without returning anything. If you want it to return a value, you need to use [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) instead.

Try:

```
$twit = get_field('twitter');
```

WordPress has a lot of functions that have fairly similar names, and it's worth a little time reading the documentation. As a rule, functions that return a value always start with `get_`.

Comment: You are right! This fixed it. Thanks. I hope that after this I'll never forget that rule. Thanks again.